# Difference between using where/lambda and for each

Tags: c#, where-clause

I'm new to C# and came across this function preformed on a dictionary.

```
 _objDictionary.Keys.Where(a => (a is fooObject)).ToList().ForEach(a => ((fooObject)a).LaunchMissles());
```

My understanding is that this essentially puts every key that is a fooObject into a list, then performs the LaunchMissles function of each. How is that different than using a for each loop like this?

```
foreach(var entry in _objDictionary.Keys)
{
    if (entry is fooObject)
    {
        entry.LaunchMissles();
    }
}
```

EDIT: The resounding opinion appears to be that there is no functional difference.

Comment: different ways of coding; looping through each element by developer is a kind of legacy way; letting Microsoft loop through is modern way :)

Comment: `How is that different than using a for each loop like this?` Nothing. And your version more readable.. Also a good blog to read https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/

Comment: It boils down to nothing more than a style difference.

Comment: also, it's worth noting that in that "linq" style, the `.Where(a => (a is fooObject))` can be just written as `.OfType<fooObject>()` (and in turn it will allow to remove manual casting in final ForEach body) and the intermediate `.ToList()` is (probably) just a waste of time and memory

Comment: @quetzalcoatl well the `ToList()` is necessary to use `ForEach()`

Comment: @Jonesopolis: yes, in plan C#, yes. But in general, no :) Just write a one-liner extension method that will do it. If you dont want to, then tons of nugets and copy-paste utils have it already

Comment: @techspider - using `foreach` is idiomatic way to iterate over collection in C#, there is nothing legacy with it

Comment: No, it is only not a style difference. Many people don't see, but there is a performance difference. Second loop pass collection only once. The first one, iterates twice and what is more - creates additional collection in memory which is not necessary. I know we have lot of ram and very fast cpu, but do not forget how to write fast apps ;)

Comment: So the main difference seems to be performance, if we have say > 100M keys then creating list just to iterate it may be slow and may consume a lot of memory. But in average programs this doesn't matter a lot

Comment: I'm closing this. Since lambda expression is in C# for almost 10 years now, and based on [this test](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2010/02/revisiting-c-loop-performance.html), they are not noticeably different.

Comment: The first one is a pseudo modern style that involves a lot of garbage with no benefit. Compare it to the functionally equivalent C#6 `foreach (var key in _objDictionary.Keys) (key as fooObject)?.LaunchMissles();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is good example of abusing LINQ - statement did not become more readable or better in any other way, but some people just like to put LINQ everywhere. Though in this case you might take the best from both worlds by doing:

```
foreach(var entry in _objDictionary.Keys.OfType<FooObject>())
{
    entry.LaunchMissles();    
}
```

Note that in your foreach example you are missing a cast to `FooObject` to invoke `LaunchMissles`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, Linq is no Voodomagic and does the same stuff under the hood that you would need to write if you werent using it. Linq just makes things easier to write but it wont beat regular code performance wise (if it really is equivalent)

In your case, your "oldschool" approach is perfectly fine and in my opinion the favorable

```
foreach(var entry in _objDictionary.Keys)
{
    fooObject foo = entry as fooObject;
    if (foo != null)
    {
        foo .LaunchMissles();
    }
}
```

Regarding the Linq-Approach:

Materializing the Sequence to a List just to call a method on it, that does the same as the code above, is just wasting ressources and making it less readable.

In your example it doesnt make a diffrence but if the source wasnt a Collection (like Dictionary.Keys is) but an IEnumerable that really works the lazy way, then there can be a huge impact.

Lazy evalutation is designed to yield items when needed, calling ToList inbetween would first gather all items before actually executing the ForEach.
While the plain foreach-approach would get one item, then process it, then get the next and so on.

If you really want to use a "Linq-Foreach" than dont use the List-Implementation but roll your own extensionmethod (like mentioned in the comments below your quesiton)

```
public static class EnumerableExtensionMethods
{ 
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach(T item in sequence) 
            action(item);
    }
}
```

---

Then still rolling with a regular foreach should be prefered, unless you put the foreach-body into a different method

```
sequence.ForEach(_methodThatDoesThejob);
```

That is the only "for me acceptable" way of using this.

Comment: Don't forget "old school" can be condensed even further with "new school". `(entry as fooObject)?.LaunchMissles()`

Comment: Right and thats even shorter than the Linq-Statement.